# CSS - Selectors with class for several labels

Tags: html, css

There is any way to simplify this code? I want to change the color to the child labels with the class "container-quill"

```
 <style>
        .container-quill p {
          color: black !important;
        }
    
        .container-quill h1 {
          color: black !important;
        }
    
      </style>
    
    <div id="editor" class="container-quill">
      <p></p>
      <h1><h1/>
     </div>
```

Comment: `.container-quill > *` for one level children.

Comment: and for two levels?

Comment: You have only `.container-quill p` and `.container-quill h1`. how can it be 2 levels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go with [`:is(...selectors)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:is):

```css
.container-quill :is(p, h1) { 
  color: black !important; 
}
```

which is the modern version of

```css
.container-quill p,
.container-quill h1 { 
  color: black !important; 
}
```

Depending on your specificity needs you can also consider [`:where(...selectors)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:where), which doesn't add anything to the specificity of the full selector it's used in, but in your case doesn't make much sense since you are applying your rules *no-matter-what* by stating `!important` anyway:

```css
.container-quill :where(p, h1) { 
  color: black !important; 
}
```

Browser support:

- [:is()](https://caniuse.com/css-matches-pseudo)
- [:where()](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_selectors_where)

Comment: Be careful with `:is` or `:where` because good support of these selectors is since year 2021 (Chrome version 88). Better use the second option for cross browser compatibility. If using `:is` read more about cross browser of this selector on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:is#cross-browser_example

Comment: @Bron Thanks for pointing out, my answer already has that information linked.